# What factors affect the number of individuals in an animal group?

Tags: zoology, demography

Social animals can live in groups whose numbers vary greatly according to species (for instance [wolves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_wolf) vs deer herds vs buffalo stampedes vs lemmings).

Is this number regulated only by environmental factors (resource abundance, position in the food web etc) or is there a genetic upper bound to this number which prevents overcrowding? Put in other words, would a species with endless food resources (but finite space) grow endlessly?

If the genetic regulation is common, then why humans don't seem to be subject to it?

Comment: What is the relationship between your title and the content of your post? Can you please try to make this clear?

Comment: Also, generally speaking, avoid saying "I heard" or "I've read" but always try to cite a source for your claims ("according to www.canislupus.com/groupSize, ...")

Comment: I am terrible sorry i am still know on this site and my english is not good as it was. But this idea come to my mind in a late night. I have just want to know if a specific number of members in groupe was evolved. I am not quite sure that wolf ancestor hunt always in 6 ( that was number from my memory, i didnt know that i have to always source for my opinion, the number is not important to me). But the question should be is the number of members important to species fylogenesis?

Comment: Don't worry, you don't have to be sorry for your english or for not asking perfect questions. It takes time to learn a language and to learn the details of the working of the SE websites.

Comment: "We are only species on this planet which have tendency to increase our population". Wrong. Every species tends to do so. Thats pretty much what reproduction is for.

Comment: Again i hit a language barier. The last comment was quite insolting. I am just want to know if some kind of animals which commit group suicide od their population Is overgrove!! I am not from preschoole. If you dont want to help me. Vote And dont let comment like this!!

Comment: @Remi.b since I think I understood what the OP wanted to ask, I decided to give it a shot and I've rewritten completely the question. L.Dodo, feel free to roll back the edit if this is not your intended question.

Comment: @LinuxBlanket Wow, there is quite a stretch between the original question and your rephrasing. Apparently the OP is happy with your rephrasing so good job!

Comment: You know the main idea was actually this, but not much people understands me even in my language. I just tried to say example, but obviously it was not the right way.  But this is exactly how my question would sound in my mother language. Anyway guys i am glad u gave me this lesson and hope i ll get answer.

Comment: Thanks @Remi.b! I think that it is actually a very good question and I'm eager to see what the others have to say about it (I remember reading something about this topic some time ago). Now I hope that the downvoted can be reversed to get some attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this depends on what you mean by group.

If you mean population then it is mostly environmental factors, although part of the environment can be other member of your species, some groups have a minimum functional size, such as passenger pigeons and breeding in groups behavior, or have density controls(if you are too spread out you might never run into another member of your species to breed with) , these internal factors are fairly rare however compared to basic resources availability, things like food, water, territory, shelter, nutrients, ect.

If you mean size of individual packs, herds, ect, then it is a mix of both, behavior which is almost always genetic is the main cause. However this behavior can be alter or triggered by environmental factors and its ultimate evolution is strongly affected by those factors as well. for instance large herd behavior will never evolve if the environment cannot support it, and if the environment changes the behavior may stop being beneficial.